# How to get the value for RichTextMode using SP Client Object Model?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone please let me know how to get the value for RichTextMode using SP Client Object Model? I used FieldMultiLineText class to check whethet the field has rich text enabled. However, I could not find a suitable method in FieldMultiLineText to check whether RichTextMode has a value.

Please let me know if this is achievable in SP Client Object Model. I know this is possible in SP Server Object Model, but my requirement is to achieve this in SP Client Object Model only.

Is parsing the value from SchemaXML is the only option available?

Thanks in advance.